# DataValueField didn't retrieve value ,although DataTextField retrieved

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

while I'm trying to use the`DataValueField`of my dropdownlist as an input int parameter in a method by using parse method`int.parse(DataValueField)`as its value should come from the database it gives me this runtime error

> Input string was not in a correct format

so I debugged the website to see where is the problem I found that it didn't retrieved its value int its`SelectedIndexChanged`method ,although the dropdownlist was filled in the`Page_Load`method
**here is the page_load method**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
writerddl.DataSource = DS.show_all_writers();
writerddl.DataValueField = "writerid";
writerddl.DataTextField = "writersname:;
writerddl.DataBind(); }
```

**and this is the SelectedIndexChanged method:**

```
protected void writerddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
writer _writer = DS.select_writer_by_id(int.Parse(writerddl.DataValueField)).Single();
usernametxt.Text = _writer.username;
passwordtxt.Text = _writer.password;
nametxt.Text = _writer.writersname;
}
```

**Note that** I'm using **LinQtoSql** ,so DS."method"() is a stored procedure

Comment: use `writerddl.SelectedValue` instead

Comment: Hmm ... seems I'm already using it ! look writer _writer = DS.select_writer_by_id(int.Parse(**writerddl.DataValueField**)).Single();

Comment: but I will try this okay

Comment: it worked ! LOL , but I still didn't understand why **writerddl.DataValueField** O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In msdn [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Use this property to specify the field that contains the value of each item in a list control.

So its simply property name, not value. For getting selected value you need use

1. [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: aha now I see where was the problem ,okay

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
writer _writer = DS.select_writer_by_id(int.Parse(writerddl.DataValueField)).Single();
```

with:

```
int i = int.Parse(writerddl.SelectedItem.Value);
writer _writer = DS.select_writer_by_id(i).Single();
```

Comment: `writerddl.DataValueField` is string `"writerid"` so `int.Parse` always raise exception

Comment: `SelectedItem` can be `null`

Answer (score 1):

To select the selected value from dropdown list, you should use writerddl.SelectedValue instead off writerddl.DataValueField

Thanks 
Parvati